# Thymeleaf How to add conditional block in javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a web application and using Thymeleaf with spring boot, I need to include an option in my javascript in-case the user locale was Arabic, so how add a conditional block and should be processed at server side?

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
        var customerNameTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.customerName}]]*/ 'customer Name';
        var amountTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.amount}]]*/ 'Amount';
        var paymentDateTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.paymentDate}]]*/ 'payment Date';
        var submissionDateTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.submissionDate}]]*/ 'submission Date';

        $("document").ready(function(e) {
            /*<![CDATA[*/
               var table = $("#example").DataTable( {
                    "ajax": {
                                "url": /*[[@{/payments/getPendingPayments}]]*/ "",
                                "type": "GET",
                                "dataSrc": ""
                            },
                    "columns": [
                                { "data": "customerFullName", "title": customerNameTitle },
                                { "data": "amount", "title": amountTitle },
                                { "data": "paymentDate", "title": paymentDateTitle },
                                { "data": "submissionDate", "title": submissionDateTitle },
                            ],
                    "language": {
                                "emptyTable": /*[[#{pendingPayments.emptyTable}]]*/ "",
                                "url":/*[[@{'/json/dataTables-ar.json'}]]*/ ""
                              }
                });
            /*]]>*/
           });
    </script>
```

the `"url":/*[[@{'/json/dataTables-ar.json'}]]*/` should only be loaded if the locale is Arabic, otherwise the the whole line shouldn't be printed in HTML page..

in JSTL I can do that using `<c:if>`

```
<c:if test="${LOCALE.language eq 'ar' }">
    ....
</c:if>
```

is there an equivalent in Thymeleaf?

Comment: I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/486

Answer (score 7):

Although, a old question, the following worked for us.

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
      var isInlineEdit = [[${param.isInlineEdit} != null ? true:false]];

      if(isInlineEdit){
        //in line edit code
      }else{
        //no in line edit
      }
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Comment: thymeleaf version ?

Comment: I think, I was using 3.0.9 at that time

Answer (score 6):

The closest I found in Thymeleaf 2 is to add a `th:if` condition to the whole `<script>` tag. You can then have multiple `<script>` tags but of course there will be come copy-pasting involved.

This feature is available in Thymeleaf 3

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var customerNameTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.customerName}]]*/ 'customer Name';
    var amountTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.amount}]]*/ 'Amount';
    var paymentDateTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.paymentDate}]]*/ 'payment Date';
    var submissionDateTitle = /*[[#{pendingPayments.submissionDate}]]*/ 'submission Date';

    $("document").ready(function(e) {
        /*<![CDATA[*/
           var table = $("#example").DataTable( {
                "ajax": {
                            // Using textual syntax from Thymeleaf 3
                            // (not sure about the exact condition for your case
                            // but this is the syntax to use)
                            [# th:if="${LOCALE.language.equals('ar') }"]
                            "url": /*[[@{/payments/getPendingPayments}]]*/ "",
                            [/]
                            "type": "GET",
                            "dataSrc": ""
                        },
                "columns": [
                            { "data": "customerFullName", "title": customerNameTitle },
                            { "data": "amount", "title": amountTitle },
                            { "data": "paymentDate", "title": paymentDateTitle },
                            { "data": "submissionDate", "title": submissionDateTitle },
                        ],
                "language": {
                            "emptyTable": /*[[#{pendingPayments.emptyTable}]]*/ "",
                            "url":/*[[@{'/json/dataTables-ar.json'}]]*/ ""
                          }
            });
        /*]]>*/
       });
</script>
```

See the **Thymeleaf textual syntax** in https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this, but alternatively you can do something like this.

Define a js variable with the expression you want & use it.

```
var condition = /*[[${LOCALE.language eq 'ar' }]]*/ 'true';

$("document").ready(function(e) {
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        if( condition) {
           var table = $("#example").DataTable( {
                "ajax": {
                            "url": /*[[@{/payments/getPendingPayments}]]*/ "",
                            "type": "GET",
                            "dataSrc": ""
                        },
                "columns": [
                            { "data": "customerFullName", "title": customerNameTitle },
                            { "data": "amount", "title": amountTitle },
                            { "data": "paymentDate", "title": paymentDateTitle },
                            { "data": "submissionDate", "title": submissionDateTitle },
                        ],
                "language": {
                            "emptyTable": /*[[#{pendingPayments.emptyTable}]]*/ "",
                            "url":/*[[@{'/json/dataTables-ar.json'}]]*/ ""
                          }
            });
        }
        else {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable( {
                "ajax": {
                            "url": /*[[@{/payments/getPendingPayments}]]*/ "",
                            "type": "GET",
                            "dataSrc": ""
                        },
                "columns": [
                            { "data": "customerFullName", "title": customerNameTitle },
                            { "data": "amount", "title": amountTitle },
                            { "data": "paymentDate", "title": paymentDateTitle },
                            { "data": "submissionDate", "title": submissionDateTitle },
                        ],
                "language": {
                            "emptyTable": /*[[#{pendingPayments.emptyTable}]]*/ ""
                          }
            });
        }
        /*]]>*/
       });
```

Comment: thought of that, but I don't find it elegant !

Comment: JavaScript natural templates work for conditions too! `/*[# th:if="${<condition>}"]*/` `<JavaScript code>` `/*[/]*/` https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-natural-templates

Answer (score -1):

Taken from Thymeleaf tutorial:

> Expression Basic Objects
>
> When evaluating OGNL expressions on the context variables, some
>   objects are made available to expressions for higher flexibility.
>   These objects will be referenced (per OGNL standard) starting with the
>   `# symbol:`
>   
>   `...`
>   `#locale: the context locale...`

OGNL stands for Object-Graph Navigation Language. So actual usage would look like this:

```
<span th:text="${#locale.country}">Should give you Country (in my case HR)</span> 
<span th:text="${#ctx.locale}">Should give you the code (in my case hr_HR)</span>
<span th:text="${#locale.country}=='ar' ? 'Arabic' : 'Not Arabic'"></span>
```

or maybe better like this:

```
<span th:text="${#strings.startsWith(#ctx.locale, 'ar')? 'Arabic' : 'Not Arabic'}></span>
```

since java provides 17 different codes for arabic, and they all start with ar, last example should work on all...

I believe you would know how to use it in your javascript.

PS> More information you can find in [Apendix A.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects)

Comment: I need it inside javascript, either the whole line ("url": ...) is there or not, l'm already using localization with labels, but this is inside dataTables..

Comment: Have you tried something like this: '"url": ([[${#strings.startsWith(#ctx.locale, 'ar')}]]) ? /*[[@{'/json/dataTables-ar.json'}]]*/:""' adding ternary expression so if locale is ar it will return provided url, and if not it will return empty string...